# How to prove even with structural induction, for expression

Tags: induction

E::= zero|two|expression + expression|expression*expression, E element of expression how do i prove E to be even.

I have no clue on how to go about tackling this.

Comment: I encourage you to proof-read your question and [use Markdown to format it](https://cs.stackexchange.com/editing-help) so it is visually easier to read.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction

Comment: What do you mean by E being "even"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove a property `p` by structural induction on your `E`, one has to prove

1. `p(zero)`
2. `p(two)`
3. for all `e1,e2` we have `p(e1) && p(e2) ==> p(e1 + e2)`
4. for all `e1,e2` we have `p(e1) && p(e2) ==> p(e1 * e2)`

That is, we have to prove that it holds for each term in the inductive definition, assuming `p` holds for the immediate subterms (induction hypothesis).

In your case, `p(e)` is "the evaluation of `e` yields an even result".

You should be able to check all the conditions above.